# Access violation reading

Tags: c++, runtime-error, buffer, access-violation

I need help with resolving this issue. I keep getting this error:

Exception thrown at 0x798F2489 (ucrtbased.dll) in XXXXX.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00F30000

The basic logic is that I receive some data from the "server" and write it to the file.

Program stops at this line dValue = *((double*)buffer);

```
for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfPoints; j++) {
        PointName = buffer;
        sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%s: ", PointName);
        // print
        this->printData(file, FileBuf);
        buffer += (strlen(PointName) + 1);

        // check if next byte is int or double
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Level") == 0 || strcmp(PointName, "Acid on output") == 0) {
            iValue = *((int*)buffer);
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%d%%\r\n", iValue);
            this->printData(file, FileBuf);
            buffer += 4; // move the point (int size) places
        }
        else {
            dValue = *((double*)buffer); // ---- Error occurs Here!
        }
```

The whole function is:

```
int PlantLogger::WriteFile(fstream* file, char* buf, int length){
struct pkg
{
    int length;
    int numberOfChannels;
    char data[1024];
};
pkg* Package = (pkg*)buf;

if (Package->length != length) {
    return 1;
}

char FileBuf[2048];

// Get the current time
time_t CurrentTime;
time(&CurrentTime);
struct tm* MyTime = localtime(&CurrentTime);

// Format the time
char TimeBuf[24];
strftime(TimeBuf, 24, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", MyTime);

// Write time to file buffer
sprintf_s(FileBuf, "\r\nMeasurement results at %s\r\n", TimeBuf);

this->printData(file, FileBuf);

char* buffer = Package->data;
char* ChannelName = { 0 };

for (int i = 0; i < Package->numberOfChannels; i++) {
    int NumberOfPoints = *((int*)buffer);
    buffer += 4;
    ChannelName = buffer;
    sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%s:\r\n", ChannelName);
    this->printData(file, FileBuf);
    buffer += (strlen(ChannelName) + 1);

    char* PointName = { 0 };
    int iValue = 0;
    double dValue = 0.0;

    for (int j = 0; j < NumberOfPoints; j++) {
        PointName = buffer;
        sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%s: ", PointName);
        // print
        this->printData(file, FileBuf);
        buffer += (strlen(PointName) + 1);

        // check if next byte is int or double
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Level") == 0 || strcmp(PointName, "Acid on output") == 0) {
            iValue = *((int*)buffer);
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%d%%\r\n", iValue);
            this->printData(file, FileBuf);
            buffer += 4; // move the point (int size) places
        }
        else {
            dValue = *((double*)buffer);
        }

        if (strcmp(PointName, "Flow speed") == 0 || strcmp(PointName, "Input solution flow") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%.1f\xB0\x43\r\n", dValue);
        }
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Temperature") == 0 || strcmp(PointName, "Output Temperature") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%.1fatm\r\n", dValue);
        }
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Pressure") == 0 || strcmp(PointName, "Output pressure") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%.1f\r\n", dValue);
        }
        if (strcmp(PointName, "PH") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%.1f\r\n", dValue);
        }
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Concentration") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%p\r\n", dValue);
        }
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Input flow") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%.3fm3/s\r\n", dValue);
        }
        if (strcmp(PointName, "Disulfid on Output") == 0) {
            sprintf_s(FileBuf, "%p/s\r\n", dValue);
        }

        this->printData(file, FileBuf);
        buffer += 8; // move the point (double size) places
    }
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: What is `buffer`? You need to make a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: First, this isn't a compile error; it's a runtime error, so you mistagged the post. Second, *"when I try to parse chars to double"* - you're not "parsing" *anything*, much less chars to `double`. Instead, you're treating the memory backdrop of `buffer` as if it *contains* a platform `double` value, and assuming it is sufficiently aligned to read that value from memory. Finally, your post should have a [mcve] , stress the minimal yet complete. It should contain code that we can compile, run and supply any required input data (that is also part of your question) to trip your error.

Comment: At a guess your buffer data doesn't have the correct endianess resulting in `NumberOfPoints` having a value much larger than you're expecting. Please provide a [mre]